# FileAlreadyExistsException not being thrown, and overwriting file

Tags: java, multithreading, file, io

This code :

```
File tmpFile = File.createTempFile(PREFIX_TMP, null, new File(reportPath));
        logger.debug("The report will be saved in the temporary file '{}'", tmpFile.getName());

        reportWriter.write(tmpFile, report);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        boolean isFileMoved = false;
        while (!isFileMoved) {
            String reportName = String.format(report.getName(), calendar.getTime());
            File reportFile = new File(reportPath, reportName);

            try {
                Files.move(tmpFile.toPath(), reportFile.toPath());
                isFileMoved = true;

                logger.info("The temporary file '{}' is renamed to '{}'", tmpFile.getName(), reportFile.getName());
            } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
                logger.warn("The file '{}' already exists in the folder '{}': adding a second to generation time",
                        reportName, reportPath);
            }

            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        }
```

generates the following, impossible, log statements :

> 2016-10-04 10:35:11,674 [WARN ] [_Executor-1] a.b.c.MyGenerator - The
>   file 'myFile_01092016103511.csv' already exists in the folder
>   '/myDir': adding a second to generation time
>
> 2016-10-04 10:35:11,677 [WARN ] [_Executor-3] a.b.c.MyGenerator - The
>   file 'myFile_01092016103511.csv' already exists in the folder
>   '/myDir': adding a second to generation time
>
> 2016-10-04 10:35:11,677 [INFO ] [_Executor-1] a.b.c.MyGenerator - The
>   temporary file 'tmp2103892505851032137.tmp' is renamed to
>   'myFile_01092016103512.csv'
>
> 2016-10-04 10:35:11,680 [INFO ] [_Executor-3] a.b.c.MyGenerator - The
>   temporary file 'tmp6843688962754506611.tmp' is renamed to
>   'myFile_01092016103512.csv'

Executor 3 overwrities the file, even though it should throw a FileAlreadyExistsException.

No exception is thrown, and the file's data has been overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Executor 3 overwrites the file, even though it should throw a FileAlreadyExistsException.

You need to use the [`ATOMIC_MOVE` option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#ATOMIC_MOVE) if you want the `Files.move(...)` to act atomically.  By default, it first tests if the destination exists and then does the move which is susceptible to [thread race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550/179850).  Here are the [javadocs for `Files.move(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-):

> ATOMIC_MOVE – Performs the move as an atomic file operation. If the file system does not support an atomic move, an exception is thrown. With an ATOMIC_MOVE you can move a file into a directory and be guaranteed that any process watching the directory accesses a complete file.

If you must have the `FileAlreadyExistsException` support then you will need to protect the moves with a `synchronized` block to only allow one thread to be running it at a time.  Given you are doing IO in this block, the `synchronized` should be little to no performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

`Files.move` uses `Files.exists` internally, the status could have changed in between when using multiple threads.